# Using a variable inside another variable

Tags: python, variables

What I am trying to do is make it so the user enters a name, which the program then takes that, adds the word `Move` to it and then grabs a set named as `*name*Move`.

Here is my code thus far, with what I want to do within `**`:

```
fredMove = set(["move1","move2","move3","move4"])  #different data
joeMove = set(["move","move","move3","move4"])     #for each name
chrisMove = set(["move1","move2","move3","move4"]) #this is just
timMove = set(["move1","move2","move3","move4"])   #easier to write out
#I have many more lists, as well

name = input("What is the name you are looking for? ").lower

def moveChecking(move1,move2,move3,move4,name):
    if (move1 not in *name*Moves):
        print("Move 1 not found!")
    if (move2 not in *name*Moves):
        print("Move 2 not found!")
    if (move3 not in *name*Moves):
        print("Move 3 not found!")
    if (move4 not in *name*Moves):
        print("Move 4 not found!")

move1 = input("Enter move 1 = ")
move2 = input("Enter move 2 = ")
move3 = input("Enter move 3 = ")
move4 = input("Enter move 4 = ")

moveChecking(move1,move2,move3,move4,name)
```

Any way to do what I want in a way that lets me avoid creating `moveChecking()` for every person's name?

Comment: You could make a dictionary with the name as key and the set as value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary.

```
moves = {
    "fred":  set(["move1","move2","move3","move4"])
    "joe":   set(["move1","move2","move3","move4"])
    "chris": set(["move1","move2","move3","move4"])
    "tim":   set(["move1","move2","move3","move4"])
}

name = input("What is the name you are looking for?")
for i in range(1, 5):
    move = input("Enter move {} = ".format(i))
    if move not in moves[name]:
        print("Move {} not found!".format(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary of the move sets then access them by name

```
moveDict = {'fred': fredMove, 'joe':joeMove } #etc
```

And then in `moveChecking` use

```
if move1 not in moveDict[name]:
    #...
```

Answer (score 1):

They're are many, many ugly ways to do what you want as you've discribed it (essentially doing `getattr` at the module level), however this seems more like a case of bad design. Instead of having a bunch of sets assigned directly to named variables, why not use a `dictionary` instead, with they `key` as the name and the `value` as the set? EX:

```
moves = {'timMove':set(["move1","move2","move3","move4"]),
 ....}
```

And then you can simply get the move set like so:

```
try:
    move_set = moves[name]
except KeyError:
     # handel a bad name here
```